# jquery logic to get the result from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, for-loop

I have a string in jquery var str like the following:

```
var str = 4-68,4-69,4-70,5-86,5-87,5-88,5-89,5-91,6-100,6-101
```

Now i want to organise the string and get the result like following:

```
var result = 4(68,69,70)|5(86,87,88,89,91)|6(100,101)
```

It seems not quite hard.  but i can't figure out the logic exactly in code.

```
var dataRecord = '4-68,4-69,4-70,5-86,5-87,5-88,5-89,5-91,6-100,6-101';
var i = 1;
var first_item = [];
var second_item = [];
var final_item = [];
var agree_ref_data = dataRecord.agreement_ref_no;
var main_arr = agree_ref_data.split(',');
for (i = 0; i < main_arr.length; ++i) {
    var second_arr = main_arr[i].split('-');

    if (jQuery.inArray(second_arr[0], first_item) == -1) {
        first_item.push(second_arr[0]);
        //second_item.push(second_arr[1]);
    }

    if (jQuery.inArray(second_arr[0], first_item) !== -1) {

        second_item.push(second_arr[1]);

    } else {
        final_result = second_item;
        //second_item=[];
    }

}
return final_result;

}
```

How can i get my desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code in pure js.No jQuery required. We first split the string by comma, then iterate the resulting array, splitting further by '-'. Then store the values as a Map (use plain js objects for this). Rest is just iterating key value pair of the object and massaging data.

```
var dataRecord = '4-68,4-69,4-70,5-86,5-87,5-88,5-89,5-91,6-100,6-101';
var a = dataRecord.split(',');
var obj = {};
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  var tmp = a[i].split('-');
  if(typeof obj[tmp[0]] !== 'object'){
    obj[tmp[0]] = [];
  }
  obj[tmp[0]].push(tmp[1]);
}
var result = '';
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + obj[key]);
    result = result + key + '(' + obj[key].join() + ')|';
  }
}
result = result.substr(0,result.length-1); // removing the last | character
```

Answer (score 1):

Full working code proposition ( no jquery needed ):

```js
var str="4-68,4-69,4-70,5-86,5-87,5-88,5-89,5-91,6-100,6-101";

//##1 . Split by ,

//we have array of elements like 4-68
var arr=str.split(",");

//results temporary object
var results={};

//##2 .Create temporary object

for ( var el in arr){

    //we have parts as [4, 68]
    var parts=arr[el].split("-");
    var main=parts[0];
    var second=parts[1];
    
    if (!results.hasOwnProperty(main)){
        
        results[main]=second;//create new string for this main
        
    }else //element with main exists so add next number
    results[main]+=","+second;//concat to string
    
}

console.log("Temporary object structure:");
console.log(results);

//ok we have array with results but we need string
var resultsStr="";

//##3. Create final string

for ( var main in results){

   if (resultsStr!="")
   resultsStr+="|"; //add | not for first one
   
   resultsStr+=main+"("+results[main]+")"; //add () to our string
   
}

console.log("Final string:");
console.log(resultsStr);
```

Steps in algorithm:

1. I split array by **,**
2. I create temporary structure where I create properties by main numbers and they value are string concatenate from second numbers
3. I create string based on temporary structure.

Algorithm will run even if main numbers will be not in right order.